# File upload with cross-fetch causes socket exception on server

Tags: fetch-api

I am trying to upload a file to a .NET Core 2.1 WebAPI service as FormData using cross-fetch. When I upload smaller files it works fine, but when I try to upload a file bigger than 2 MB, the server throws a socket exception, indicating that the connection is closed by the client.

Are there any options I can use in the fetch call or any client settings that prevent the client from closing the connection?

Comment: _"the server throws a socket exception, indicating that the connection is closed by the client"_ - how do you determine this?

Comment: @CodeCaster the exception message is "SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and is thrown on the line "var file = Request.Form.Files[0];"

Comment: The problem is gone now, after I upgraded to .Net Core 2.2.